# Changing colors and adding labels to a nestedtemp() plot using the vegan package

Tags: r, plot, vegan, presentation

I used the R package vegan to check for nestedness in my dataset:

```
bc_rp <- read.csv("BC_RPc.csv", na.strings = c("","NA"), header=TRUE, check.names = FALSE)

bc_rp

bc <- data.frame(
  cell_layer = c("H", "B", "A", "G", "O"),
  Np = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0),
  Pn = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1),
  Npn = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
  Npnp = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
  Pnp = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  Pnpn = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0)
)


# Renamed the columns to be easier to manipulate and have no special characters
# colnames(hc) <-c('species', 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g')

# Transpose the rows and columns in data. 
bc_t <-t(bc)

out_bc_t <- nestedtemp(bc_t)
out_bc_t
#nestedness temperature: 10.24168 
#with matrix fill 0.4 

plot(out_bc_t, kind="incid")
```

And this code works as expected to produce a nestedness temperature and a plot.

nestedness temperature: 10.24168
with matrix fill 0.4
[image: Nestedness Plot]

However, I, wish I could change the color of the plot to be something other than Red, and add labels for each cell type, and for the categories(np, pn, etc) How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point is the documentation of the function (try `?nestedtemp`). The `plot` function for the `nestedtemp` seems to have argument `col` that can be used to set the colours, and `names` that defaults to `names = FALSE`, but setting `TRUE` would add names (according to documentation at least – I didn't try). If these do not help you, please ask a more detailed question.

Comment: Thank you! I had tried col, but it changes the color of the whole plot, so you can't see the presence/absence data on it. So I'm still not sure how to change the color. But the  "names = TRUE" worked! So now I have the labels which really helps.

Comment: For colour, you must supply a palette of colours. Incidence plots need two colours `plot(..., kind="incidence", col=c("white","black"))`, and temperature plots a wider palette, where the first colour is absence (cold) and last colour is the hottest. See default in `?plot.nestedtemp`.